# Concerns about my Euphorbia spiralis

Tags: euphorbia

My Euphorbia spiralis family has done well, even though I didn't know until I read it recently that I should have separated the first baby (now a big toddler) when it was small. I have two concerns: 
1. should I still try to separate the small one, or will it just grow like a Siamese twin at this point? 
2. The mother has two more small babies (which I haven't yet separated). I examine my plants every day (ever since an Opuntia was done in by scale last year), and yesterday I found two very small cottony tufts on one of the babies. Mealybugs?? I removed them entirely and don't see anything else today--does anyone have some advice if I do see more signs of trouble?

I'd be so grateful for help! Also, can I snip off the dead ends of "branches" on the mother plant?

Comment: Euphorbia is a super duper plant to be...raising.  Don't know if you are saying you've got but one species but we really really need photos!  Mealy bug sounds right and good to remove.  There are probably eggs and you shall have more but, hey, a few ain't gonna harm your plant right now.  I've never grown this guy but you should know Euphobia all parts are poisonous...wear gloves don't allow pets to munch!  If a part of your plant is dead take it off.  Don't 'mist' these plants...tell us what you've done or not done for soil, lighting, fertilizer, type of pot and how you planted your plant...

Comment: accesstoinsight

Comment: What are you saying?  I'm here right now fighting off these manic puppies....